# How to store the return value of a function initially before start executing test cases in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am a newbie in robot framework . I want to store the return value of a function initially to a variable before start executing the test. My idea is to use this variable in each and every test case. I don't want to execute the function in each test case. I will give you a sample reproducible code.

This is the robot file that I am using `TestCase.robot` and this is the current implementation

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Status.py



*** Test Cases ***
TC_01
    ${store_this_value_here}=    get_value    #This get_value function will always return 2
    ${rv}    Set Variable    ${2}    #${}    #Setting this ${rv} as 2
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    ${store_this_value_here}

TC_02
    ${store_this_value_here}=    get_value    #This get_value function will always return 2
    ${rv}    Set Variable    ${2}    #${}    #Setting this ${rv} as 2
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    ${store_this_value_here}

TC_03
    ${store_this_value_here}=    get_value    #This get_value function will always return 2
    ${rv}    Set Variable    ${2}    #${}    #Setting this ${rv} as 2
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    ${store_this_value_here}
```

As you can see I am calling the function `get_value` in each and every test case. But I want to make this `get_value` as common so that the `${store_this_value_here}` will be stored initially. I don't want to execute this function before every test cases but only once. I am not referring to the `Test Suite`which is defined [here](https://github.com/robotframework/QuickStartGuide/blob/master/QuickStart.rst#test-suites)

I want to have something like this

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Status.py


*** Keywords ***
${store_this_value_here}=    get_value    #Place like this

*** Test Cases ***
TC_01
    ${rv}    Set Variable    ${2}    #${}   
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    ${store_this_value_here}

TC_02
    ${rv}    Set Variable    ${2}    #${}    
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    ${store_this_value_here}

TC_03
    ${rv}    Set Variable    ${2}    #${}    
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${rv}    ${store_this_value_here}
```

I know this implementation is wrong and because of this I am getting the error in the console like this

```
TestRobot
==============================================================================
TC_01                                                                 | FAIL |
Variable '${store_this_value_here}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC_02                                                                 | FAIL |
Variable '${store_this_value_here}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC_03                                                                 | FAIL |
Variable '${store_this_value_here}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the code in a suite or test setup, and then use [Set suite variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) to make it visible to all test cases.

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup  Initialize suite variables

*** Keywords ***
Initialize suite variables
    ${store_this_value_here}=    get_value
    set suite variable  ${store_this_value_here}
```